# SendGrid sending to multiple recipients using api v3 & PHP library in Wordpress function

Tags: php, wordpress, sendgrid-api-v3

I am using SendGrid v3 api with the php library to try and send to multiple recipients as part of a WordPress function. I can successfully send emails using the SendGrid sample code and hard coding the multiple recipients. However, when I query the database to try build the list of to: email addresses it always fails with a 400 error. Here is the SendGrid code I am working with. It works fine with live data and hard coded. However, I can't seem to properly build the $tos array from my database query. I have read the documentation and every tutorial I can find. I also contacted Sendgrid support.

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");
$tos = [ 
    "test+test1@example.com" => "Example User1",
    "test+test2@example.com" => "Example User2",
    "test+test3@example.com" => "Example User3"
];
$email->addTos($tos);
$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
"text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
}
```

Here is my WordPress query: $sends = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `test`" );

How do I properly code the $tos variable from my database query so that $email->addTos($tos) does not error out?

Thanks.

Comment: You should remove the plus(+) symbols in the test email address  to check if SendGrid isn't choking on them.

Comment: Please post the structure of your `test` database.

Comment: test database has 2 columns - id and email.

Comment: The + is not the issue. I used real email addresses and the sample code works fine. The issue is when I try to dynamically populate the email addresses from the database.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/127), the `addTos` function is defunct and no longer supported in SendGrid's API: "The `addTos()` method was moved to `addTo()` and does not currently support arrays being passed in".

Therefore:

Using your `test` database:

```
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail(); 
$email->setFrom("test@example.com", "Example User");

$userResults = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `email` FROM `test`", ARRAY_A ); //Select as Associative Array
foreach($userResults as $userKey => $userValue){
  $userEmail = $userValue['email']);
  if ( is_email( $userEmail ) ) {  //Validate  properly formatted email structure
      $email->addTo($userValue['email']);  // If you hade a name column you could use: $email->addTo($userValue['email'], $userValue['name']);
  }
}

$email->setSubject("Sending with SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent(
"text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>"
);
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid(getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY'));
try {
    $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
    print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
    print_r($response->headers());
    print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: '.  $e->getMessage(). "\n";
}
```

Using `wp_users` database:

```
$userResults = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `user_email`, `user_nicename` FROM `wp_users`", ARRAY_A );
foreach($userResults as $userKey => $userValue){
    $email->addTo($userValue['user_email'], $userValue['user_nicename']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution will work in the limited situation of adding emails to "To" field. However, the article you cited about addTos being deprecated is over 3 years old and was written about an older api. The current api v3 does use addTos and uses the same format for addCcs and addBccs so I'm still looking for a solution that will address all three.

Comment: When your solution is applied to the addBccs it generates the following warnings and no bccs are sent:

Warning: current() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in /sendgrid-php/lib/mail/Mail.php on line 281

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /sendgrid-php/lib/mail/Mail.php on line 291

Answer (score 0):

I think @Jamie_D have some misunderstanding about `addTos` method because as per now in  19 June 2019 i am using `addTos` method and it is working perfectly ok,

**Edit:** and now sendgrid's employee has also confirmed it see this link:https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/127#issuecomment-508330993

when First time i have used it i got errors also so i have debugged and printed some variable in sendgrid library and i have got the point, may be you are also missing that point so you are getting error.

in `$tos` array you have to **provide associative array in which email should be the keys and user's name should be the values**, see below example:

**Syntax:**

```
$tos = [ 
        //user emails       =>  user names  
        "user1@example.com" => "Example User1",
        "user2@example.com" => "Example User2",
        "user3@example.com" => "Example User3"
    ];
    $email->addTos($tos);
```

**Example** using wp_users table:

```
$tos = array();
$userResults = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `user_email`, `user_nicename` FROM `wp_users`", ARRAY_A );
foreach($userResults as $user){
    $tos[$user['user_email']]= $user['user_nicename'];
}
$email->addTos($tos);
```

try it, it will definitely works and if doesn't then tell me in comments, thanks.